# Restsharp post method is not working, Web api post method receiving null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am calling Web API post method Restsharp C# in MVC. below is code for web api and controller method.

API method

```
public class GrowthController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IEncoderDecoder encoderDecoderRepository;
    public GrowthController(IEncoderDecoder _EncoderDecoderRepository)
    {
        this.encoderDecoderRepository = _EncoderDecoderRepository;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public object EncodeDecodeString([FromBody]string data)
    {
        // data value is coming null.
    }
}
```

Calling Web Api.

```
var clientR = new RestClient("https://service.testing.com/Api/Growth/EncodeDecodeString");
    var request = new RestRequest();
    var body = new
    {
        data = "host_environment",
        submit = "Password"
    };
    request.AddJsonBody(body);
    request.Method = Method.POST;

    var response1 = clientR.Execute(request);
    var content = response1.Content;
}
```

Comment: The request is working correctly, you can easily check it in Fiddler. Your controller method needs to accept an object parameter of type that has both `data` and `submit` properties and you need to take care that serialization configuration matches. If you use System.Text.Json, keep in mind that it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing this header from your client:

`request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`

This will most probably solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but its not working for me. I tried the same but still API method receiving null value.

Comment: `AddJsonBody` sets the content type properly. There's no need to set headers manually.